# Why is my arithmetic condition evaluated as true?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I have a sample logic. By calculation, it is `-2 > 0` . This is a false condition and I get no result, but I am getting the value as `abcd`.

```
#!/bin/bash
Val1=1
Val2=1
Val3=2
Name=abcd
log=/tmp/log
if [ "$((Val1-(Val2 + Val3))) -ge 0" ] ; then echo "$Name"  | tee -a "$log"; fi
```

I have verified on ShellCheck, and it is giving me this message. I couldn't get how to fix this?

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 7:
if [ "$((Val1-(Val2 + Val3))) -ge 0" ] ; then echo "$Name"  | tee -a "$log"; fi
                             ^-- SC2157: Argument to implicit -n is always true due to literal strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[ 'a string' ]`, that's the same as `[ -n 'a string' ]`: it checks if the parameter is non-empty. You're providing the argument `"$((Val1-(Val2 + Va3))) -ge 0"`, which evaluates to the string `"-2 -ge 0"`. "Implicit `-n`" means that the shell really checks

```sh
if [ -n "-2 -ge 0" ]
```

and that is always true, because that's not an empty string.

The reason is your quoting. This would work instead:

```sh
if [ "$((Val1-(Val2 + Val3)))" -ge 0 ]
```

Strictly speaking, the quotes aren't necessary, but they don't hurt, either.

Or, since you're using Bash, you could use an arithmetic conditional:

```sh
if ((Val1 - (Val2 + Val3) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured after posting the question

```
#!/bin/bash
Val1=1
Val2=1
Val3=2
Name=abcd
log=/tmp/log
if [ "$((Val1-(Val2 + Val3)))" -ge 0 ] ; then echo "$Name"  | tee -a "$log"; fi
```